# how to use constant from class as an argument definition in php function?

Tags: php, oop, function

I have a class:

```
class FetchMode 
{
 const FetchAll = 0;
 const FetchOne = 1;
 const FetchRow = 2;}
```

and a function:

```
function getRecordSet(FetchMode $FetchMode){ some switch cases }
```

I would like to use $FetchMode as switch case criteria but receiving an error:
**Catchable fatal error: Argument  passed to getRecordSet() must be an instance of FetchMode, integer given**

this is how I call a function:

```
getRecordSet(FetchMode::FetchOne);
```

I would like to offer a list of possible choices in calling a function.
Is it possible in php?

Comment: FetchMode::FetchOne resolves to 1, so you actually pass 1 to the function, not an object of the type FetchMode. I don't know what you want to achive, but keep in Mind that you must pass an object of type FetchMode to your function, so you need some kind of ``$fm = new FetchMode();``

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've [hinted](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) PHP to expect an instance of `FetchMode` (just like it says in the error message), but `FetchMode::FETCH*` passes the constant *value*. You'd have to use some sort of Enum instance (which we dont have natively in PHP. (Oh well, there is `SplEnum` but who uses that?)) or change the method signature to exclude the typehint.

However, instead of a Switch/Case you could [solve this more easily via Polymorphism](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism) and a [Strategy pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy), e.g. instead of doing something like

```
public function getRecordSet($mode)
{
    switch ($mode) {
        case FetchMode::ALL:
            // code to do a fetchAll
            break;
        case FetchMode::ONE:
            // code to do a fetchOne
            break;
        default:
    }
}
```

which will increase the [Cylcomatic Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) of your class and forces changes to that class and `FetchMode` whenever you need to add additional FetchModes, you can do:

```
public function getRecordSet(FetchMode $fetchModeStrategy)
{
    return $fetchModeStrategy->fetch();
}
```

and then have an [interface](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) to [protect the variation](http://martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/protectedVariation.pdf)

```
interface FetchMode
{
    public function fetch();
}
```

and add concrete `FetchMode` classes for each supported FetchMode

```
class FetchOne implements FetchMode
{
    public function fetch()
    {
        // code to fetchOne
    }
}
class FetchAll …
class FetchRow …
```

This way, you'll never have to touch the class with that `getRecordSet` method again because it will work for any class implementing that `FetchMode` inteface. So whenever you have new FetchModes, you simply add a new class, which is much more maintainable in the long run.

Comment: And 8 years after, I still find your answer one of the best approachs I have read about this.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by

> would like to offer a list of possible choices in calling a function. Is it possible in php?

but for the error part: Imagine you have a var, e.g. `$foo`. When you do `echo $foo` you don't get the name of the var but its value. This is because a var has a name and points to a value.  Every access to the var basically returns the value it points to. Its the same with constants; You put the constant name in there, but basically you are pointing to your stored value. Which means `getRecordSet(FetchMode::FetchOne);` and `getRecordSet(1);` is the same.

So, `getRecordSet(FetchMode $FetchMode)` raises `must be an instance of FetchMode` because `FetchMode::FetchOne` points to an integer.

To fix this, you need to use `getRecordSet(int $FetchMode)`.

Comment: I don't want to force other developers to know which choice have which value. That's why I'm trying to use functionname(FetchMode::FetchOne) instead of functionname(1)

Comment: they don't have to know. You can still use `FetchMode::FetchOne` but your function declaration still takes an `int`and not a `FetchMode` as an argument (because your argument points to an `int` and not to an instance of `FetchMode`) unless you're using some strategy pattern as Gordon explains in his answer.