# php method argument as enum/const

Tags: php, enums, constants

Is there a way to allow enum or const as method argument in PHP. In Qt/C++ you could use it like this, but ofcourse C++ supports that (language dependant).

```
Qt/C++/SslSocket

enum PeerVerifyMode {
    VerifyNone,
    QueryPeer,
    VerifyPeer,
    AutoVerifyPeer
};

void setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::PeerVerifyMode mode);
```

I PHP I tried this:

**First:**

```
class Controller_My
{
  const MENU_FRONT   = 0;
  const MENU_SESSION = 1;

  public function render($menu_model)
  {
    $menu_model = intval($menu_model);

    if( $menu_model === 0 )
      $menu = new Model_Menu_Front();

    if( $menu_model === 1 )
      $menu = new Model_Menu_Session();
  }
}
```

I've read also this post [how to use constant from class as an argument definition in php function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532645/how-to-use-constant-from-class-as-argument-definition-in-php-function). But even with  http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism interface/implements solution if you are paranoined you use switch/if statement. Like this:

```
class EmployeeType...
  int payAmount(Employee emp) {
    switch (getTypeCode()) {
        case ENGINEER:
           return emp.getMonthlySalary();
        case SALESMAN:
           return emp.getMonthlySalary() + emp.getCommission();
        case MANAGER:
           return emp.getMonthlySalary() + emp.getBonus();
        default:
           throw new RuntimeException("Incorrect Employee");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [SplEnum](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splenum.php) and the user notes for an example.

Comment: why not present a proper sample code ?
"user notes" are not static and not specific.

Comment: Link is dead. Answer should include what is relevant for the context.